# Why incorrect order of navigation from SplashScreen to MainPage

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await, splash-screen

I trying to understand an [example app](https://github.com/microsoft/InventorySample) by Microsoft. Now I can't repeat the next part. The app have classes [App](https://github.com/microsoft/InventorySample/blob/master/src/Inventory.App/App.xaml.cs) and [ExtendedSplach](https://github.com/microsoft/InventorySample/blob/master/src/Inventory.App/Views/SplashScreen/ExtendedSplash.xaml.cs). I want to repeat loading by `ExtendedSplash`. In my case, it's simple switch from splash to main page after some delay.

## Introduction

The example to do like this.

If app runs with breakpoints on line `.Content = extendedSplash` and `.Content = rootFrame`, then the first will be `extendedSplash`. But line `.Content = extendedSplash` the follow after `.Content = rootFrame`. The constructor `ExtendedSplash` calls `LoadDataAsync` that set `.Content = rootFram` by first.

However, method `LoadDataAsync` contains `await` call

```
await Startup.ConfigureAsync();
```

I think that thus the first will `extendedSplash`. And we will see loading page.

**class App**

```
...
bool loadState = (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated);
ExtendedSplash extendedSplash = new ExtendedSplash(e, loadState);
Window.Current.Content = extendedSplash;
Window.Current.Activate();
```

**class ExtendedSplash**

```
public ExtendedSplash(IActivatedEventArgs e, bool loadState)
{
    ...
    LoadDataAsync(this.activatedEventArgs);
}

private async void LoadDataAsync(IActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(LoginView), shellArgs);
    Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

## Problem

I tried to repeat the same. I want see `loading` and then swith to other page. But my case with breakpoints looks like the first `.Content = rootFrame` and the second `.Content = extendedSplash`. Thus my queue are logo app with delay 5 seconds and then page with `extendedSplash`. The page `rootFrame` losing.

I will grateful for any help.

## My code

I did the same by `App` class

```
bool loadState = (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated);
ExtendedSplash extendedSplash = new ExtendedSplash(e, loadState);
Window.Current.Content = extendedSplash;
Window.Current.Activate();
```

And the next by `ExtendedSplash`

```
public ExtendedSplash(IActivatedEventArgs e, bool loadState)
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    Window.Current.SizeChanged += new WindowSizeChangedEventHandler(ExtendedSplash_OnResize);

    this.splashScreen = e.SplashScreen;
    this.activatedEventArgs = e;

    OnResize();
    rootFrame = new Frame();
    LoadDataAsync(activatedEventArgs);
}

private async void LoadDataAsync(IActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    await Test();

    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    Window.Current.Activate();
}

private async Task Test()
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    while (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 5000) ;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is in fact in the `Test()` method. You have marked is `async`, but that doesn't make the method asynchronous. Instead, your code will actually be stuck for five seconds in blocking manner in the `while` loop.

Try the following version:

```
private async Task Test()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

This form of code is *in fact* asynchronous, so as a result the UI thread will be free to display the splash screen in the meantime.

In general - async methods run on the thread that calls them until they hit an "actual" asynchronous code - for example I/O bound async method or when you run your code with `await Task.Run(()=>{...}`.

Comment: Why the same logic does not work with method `LoadDataAsync()`, when do `await Test()`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this question, could you say it in different words / update the question?

Comment: @Viewed Because `Test()` is not doing anything asynchronous. In fact, it's not even waiting. It's constantly busy checking the current state of the `Stopwatch`. You will see this if you look at your CPU usage during those 5 seconds.

Comment: Yes, as @GabrielLuci says, it keeps checking the state of Stopwatch and never releases the UI thread to be able to actually show the extended splash screen for the whole 5 seconds. When you use `Task.Delay` instead, the waiting is asynchronous, so the UI thread is free to do whatever required.

Comment: Can you find code into example by microsoft, that do `await task`? I see only `async/await` without `tasks`. As if all to do `sync`.